# jQuery.post() and PHP interaction

Tags: php, jquery, post

I have a problem with jQuery and PHP... so here is my jQuery code:

```
var rino = "Renaro";
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.post('form.php', { test: rino } );
});
```

and here PHP

```
echo $_POST['test'];
```

From documentation I understood that after jQuery there should be assigned `rino` value to  `$_POST['test']`.. But it doesn't echo's value.. and gives PHP error `PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  test`

What am I doing wrong?

Here is full code of file

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var rino = "Renaro";
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.post('form.php', { "test" : "rino" } );
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="content">
    <?php echo $_POST['test']; ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How are you checking the results of the AJAX call? Are there any JS errors?

Comment: No errors in chrome console

Comment: Do a print_r($_POST); on the form.php

Comment: Is this really the only line in your PHP file? You also should provide a callback to do something with the response.

Comment: @FelixKling I don't think the OP is interested in getting the return results, he only wants to send the data to the server.

Comment: @jerome.s: Well, there is an `echo` in the code... why would you output something if you were not interested in it.

Comment: Why to you request the same file from where the request is launched ?

Comment: So, the code you posted is your `form.php` file? If so, you get the notice because you open it directly in the browser. At this moment, `$_POST['test']` does not exist indeed.  Then jQuery makes the request to the server, asking for the same file, it sends back the HTML output, this time with the correct value for `$_POST['test']`, but since you are not doing anything with the response, you didn't notice that it indeed "works". Open the developer tools of your browser and have a look at the network tab. It should show you the requests and responses.

Comment: @FelixKling I was thinking the echo was for testing purpose, and that he wouldn't need it in javascript, only in the PHP file. Since the edit, I reckon you're right.

Comment: That's exactly what I answered. The $_POST is only available when you're doing the actual request of `form.php`, but the jQuery post won't ever be able to change it after the page is already loaded. Why downvote me?

Comment: If this is not the `form.php` file, the `<?php echo $_POST['test']; ?>` statement is in the wrong file ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your code to this, that should work.

Note that I remove the quote from `rino` because it's a variable.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var rino = "Renaro";
            $.post('form.php', { "test" : rino }, function(data) {
                $('#content').html(data);
             }); 
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="content">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Am I understanding you right?

Do are doing the jQuery in one file and calling `form.php` in another browser tab?

The problem then should be:

The jQuery is posting to `form.php` and it will `echo` the content of the variable `test` (but there is nobody viewing this, because it's not safed). You could better test this by either returning the result back to the jQuery or by saving it to a file.

But as you will open `form.php`, will not see this result, because your call isn't the call, that is done by jQuery, so there isn't any value set for `test`.

Comment: You might not have expressed your thought clear enough. Example code might make it clearer too.

Comment: +1 You understood the problem perfectly, and you are absolutely right but you haven't articulated it very well.

Answer (score 0):

try this

php

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['test']){echo $_POST['test']; }?>  // check if there post then echo
```

**jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var rino = "Renaro";
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.post('form.php', { test : rino } );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Nop still the same - nothing

Answer (score 0):

Create a div with a "dummy" class in your html and try with:

```
var rino="Renaro";
callme(rino);
function callme(rino){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {test: rino},
        url: 'form.php',
        success: function(str){
            $('.dummy').html(str);  
        },
        error: function(){
            $('.dummy').html("Nope, nothing here");
        }
    });
}
```

Edit: but not in the same page! The page with the JS and HTML should differ from the one with the PHP and $_POST...

Comment: This worked even if the same page. It echo's value but gives PHP error PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  test

Comment: @user1599935: Of course because when you open the file in the browser, you are making a GET request, not a POST request, and hence `$_POST['test']` is not set. I think you are still confused by how PHP, JavaScript and Ajax work together. The browser makes a request to the server to get the file. PHP is executed on the *server side* and the result is the HTML page which is sent to the browser. The browser then executes the JavaScript, which makes *another* request to the server and gets *another* HTML page back. This data (page) does *not* replace the current page, it is on you to handle the

Comment: response in JavaScript. You would typically make the Ajax request to another file/URL, not the same one.

Comment: Yeah, you'r right my knowledge about JavaScript etc is very low, I just got the need to implement one thing from it and probably will start it learning too :)